# Broadcast Audio using a server from multiple Live Audio inputs

Tags: audio

We have multiple live audio input streams to be broadcast using a server.
One live Audio stream will be played at a time interchangeably.

It is preferred if any software is available for UBUNTU.
We have several locations to collect live audio stream on an event. Then we need to periodically cover all the locations using a central server, to work as broadcast server.It is fine if the output can be broadcast using web browser. or even through the software it self.

We have tried ip based solutions, but all the audio streams doesn't remain in same network.Therefore that solution doesn't work.

We want any free software recommendation on above requirement.

Comment: What OS? Broadcast to what - browsers? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.